# ARVR Toolkit Fragment Payload

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-arvr

I'm trying to get fragment data using the VRAR Toolkit API so that we can make some optimizations to the mesh data. We can create a scene, process the SVF into toolkit scene, and scene process finishes, but we're having issues when we actually have to get the fragment data.

Using the following endpoint:

`https://developer-api.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit/MODEL_URN/mesh/MESH_ID/FRAG_ID`

Returns a 200 with an octet-stream, but I can't find any documentation as to what the contents of the octet-stream are. According to the documentation (https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/1.2.1#/ARVR-Toolkit/get_asset_fragment) we can specify whether to use `legacy` or `openctm`.

1) What is the legacy format? How can verts, normals, uv, etc. be extracted?

2) I tried the openctm option and saved the returned octet-stream to a .ctm file and tried opening in the OpenCTM Viewer available from (http://openctm.sourceforge.net/) but always get CTM_BAD_FORMAT error when trying to open the file for viewing. How can I confirm my openctm payload is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The SVF format (including the mesh data format) isn't publicly documented but you can get some idea about its structure from the AR/VR Toolkit's Unity package source code: https://github.com/wallabyway/ARVRToolkit/blob/master/unity-src/ARVRToolkit/Assets/Forge/ARKit/MeshRequest.cs#L54-L89.

Comment: Got it. I was also looking through the update Forge toolkit Unity examples here: https://github.com/wallabyway/forgetoolkitsamples/blob/master/ForgeToolkitSamples/Assets/Forge/Code%20Base/MeshRequest2.cs#L120

And noticed that uses openCTM, however, when I try opening the payload in the openCTM viewer it doesn't work. And from looking at the code there's an offset that needs to be applied. Any chance we can get some documentation or clarification on what that offset it?